# Android: Is it possible to include color definitions from files in colors.xml

Tags: android, xml, colors

The color definition in the application I work in are quite complex.
Among other things:

- there are legacy definitions
- there are basic color definitions
- there is a separate layer of color definitions that references the basic definitions

I would like to organize these color definitions in multipole files, possibly including each other.

(How) Is that possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define your colors in any file as long as it is in the `values` directory.

In your case you could do something like this:

```
values
|-- legacy_colors.xml
|-- basic_colors.xml
|-- high_level_colors.xml
```

There is no way for the files include each other, but you can reference the values from other files like that:

File: `basic_colors.xml`

```
<color name="basic_blue">#00bbff</color>
```

File: `high_level_colors.xml`

```
<color name="list_item_backgroud">@color/basic_blue</color>
```

Comment: "There is no way for the files include each other" and there is no need to include them :) All colors will be in `R.color`

Comment: Yeah, true. I've only answered the authors question :)

Answer (score 3):

You can have as many files in `res/values/` (or `res/values-.../` for various configurations) as you want. Any of them can define colors. While convention uses a `colors.xml` file, that is not a requirement.

There is no notion of "including each other", though. All color resources are in the same namespace (`R.color.XXXX`).